# Error when inserting special characters such as Ñ and accents á, é, í, ó, ú. using BULK OPENROWSET from python in a linux server

Tags: python, pandas, linux, bulkinsert, openrowset

I am having problems inserting information into a table in my SQLSERVER 2008 database from my python project deploy in a linux server using OPENROWSET BULK and even though the `CSV` file generates special characters such as Ñ, á, é, etc... When inserting it into the database these characters are corrupted.

This is where I create my `CSV` file:

(this work in a windows server, but when the project is running in a Linux server doesn't recognize the encoding and generate error).

`dfClientes.to_csv(cvs_path, index=False, sep=';', encoding='ANSI')`

I run a shutil copy to move that file to a specific path

`shutil.copy(cvs_path, ruta_destinoCSV)`

and I run the OPENROWSET BULK:

```
bulk_insert_query = f'''INSERT INTO sgCliente (IdCliente,NomCliente,ApeCliente,NumDocumento,IdTipoDoc,NomTipoDoc,CodTipoDoc,Tip_docu,Sexo,FactorRh,GrupSangre,EstadoCivil,FecNacimiento,eMail,TelMovil,PrimerNombre,SegundoNombre,PrimerApellido,SegundoApellido,IndCentroExcelencia,IndDatosPersonal,IndHabilitado,IdTercero,CodUES)
                    SELECT * FROM  OPENROWSET(
                    BULK '{ ruta_destinoCSV }',
                    FORMATFILE='{ ruta_destinoXML }',
                    FIRSTROW = 2) as t
                '''
```

This is the content of my XML fiel that I use as a formatfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <RECORD>
      <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="101" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="101" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="20" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="1" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="30" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="2" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="3" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="254" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="254" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="11" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="254" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="12" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="254" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="13" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="8"/>
      <FIELD ID="14" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="15" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="15" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="16" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="17" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="18" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="19" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="20" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" />
      <FIELD ID="21" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" />
      <FIELD ID="22" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" />
      <FIELD ID="23" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" />
      <FIELD ID="24" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='\n' MAX_LENGTH="5" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
   </RECORD>
   <ROW>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="IdCliente" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="NomCliente" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="ApeCliente" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="NumDocumento" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="IdTipoDoc" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="NomTipoDoc" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="CodTipoDoc" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="Tip_docu" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="Sexo" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="10" NAME="FactorRh" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="11" NAME="GrupSangre" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="12" NAME="EstadoCivil" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="13" NAME="FecNacimiento" xsi:type="SQLDATETIME"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="14" NAME="eMail" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="15" NAME="TelMovil" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="16" NAME="PrimerNombre" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="17" NAME="SegundoNombre" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="18" NAME="PrimerApellido" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="19" NAME="SegundoApellido" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="20" NAME="IndCentroExcelencia" xsi:type="SQLBIT"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="21" NAME="IndDatosPersonal" xsi:type="SQLBIT"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="22" NAME="IndHabilitado" xsi:type="SQLBIT"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="23" NAME="IdTercero" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="24" NAME="CodUES" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
   </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

When I use `UTF-8` this is what I try to insert

[image: These are a few lines from my CSV file]

And this is what it looks in my database

[image: This is what it looks like in my database]

Comment: These aren't special characters. You used the wrong codepage to read non-Unicode text and store it into non-Unicode columns. ` encoding='ANSI'` is definitely wrong - that's the 7-bit US-ASCII encoding that can't even handle English words with diacritics. If you wanted to insert data into SQL Server, [df.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) would work without problems. If the *table* uses `nvarchar` instead of `varchar` you won't have to worry about encodings at all

Comment: The "bulk insert" query is overcomplicated too. You can use [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). If you want to exclude some rows or rename columns, do so *before* you use `to_sql` or `to_csv`. It's a lot easier to modify a Dataframe into the form you want than try to do so in a BULK INSERT call

Comment: both answer does not work for me, as i said before, the ANSI encoding only works when de microservice is deploying in a windows server, i need the encoding that works in linux server.

Comment: They work for everyone else, which is why I can just type Αυτό Εδώ knowing it will appear without problems. Stack Overflow uses SQL Server and `nvarchar` columns. The problem is in the code that was never posted. You didn't post any code that uses BULK INSERT with a Unicode encoding. You didn't post any code that uses `to_sql`. `encoding='ANSI'` is 100% wrong, unless you explicitly set both the shell and column collations to Latin1 - which will mangle any characters outside the Latin1 range